# Access values of certain id and use them to convert a text into link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element

I want to access the values of input ids and make a certain link using them,  then make the values of banana and apple clickable by using jquery as there are multiple div's of "panel-defaul" i want to make all those clickables by using their input id's values......

I have already tried to access the values of input ids and gets no success

var id1 = $(".input-group.input-group-lg").attr("market'0'.list'0'.made").value;

console.log(id1);

```
            <div class="panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-11">
                                    <br>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr align="left">
                                                <td><strong>1</strong></td>
                                                <td><i>Banana</i></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr align="left">
                                                <td><strong>2</strong></td>
                                                <td><i>Apple</i></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">

                                <input id="market'0'.list'0'.made" name="xxx1" value="Fruit1" type="hidden">

                                <input id="market'0'.list'1'.made" name="xxx2" value="Fruit2" type="hidden">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Expected result should be like this:

banana is "clickable" redirects to a link "www.xyz.com/Fruit1"

apple is "clickable" redirects to a link "www.xyz.com/Fruit2"

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but here's how you get the values into the DOM:

```js
var $fruits = $(".input-group.input-group-lg").children();

var $newDiv = $('.links');
$fruits.each(function (index, el) {
  var $newLink = $('<a></a>');
  var link = 'http://www.example.com/' + el.value
  
  $newLink.text(el.value)
  $newLink.attr('href', link)
  $newDiv.append($newLink)
  $newDiv.append('<br />')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-11">
                                    <br>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr align="left">
                                                <td><strong>1</strong></td>
                                                <td><i>Banana</i></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr align="left">
                                                <td><strong>2</strong></td>
                                                <td><i>Apple</i></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">

                                <input id="market'0'.list'0'.made" name="xxx1" value="Fruit1" type="hidden">

                                <input id="market'0'.list'1'.made" name="xxx2" value="Fruit2" type="hidden">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="links">
            </div>
```

Comment: appreciate your help hybrid but currently i only want to access the input id's value..keeping in mind that there are a number of panel-body divs, like here(https://codepen.io/dhaval-verma/pen/EJgPZG) ....i need to access them all one by one

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
var id1 = $(".input-group.input-group-lg input[name='xxx1']").val();
var id2 = $(".input-group.input-group-lg input[name='xxx2']").val();
console.log( id1 + ' | ' + id2 );
```